# ¿Como almacenar una imagen con Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, html5, blade

**Desde mi formulario intento guardar una imagen para el perfil del usuario**, la verdad no comprendo porque recibo el siguiente error de validacion

[image: Formulario]

En el formulario estoy indicando lo siguiente: **(enctype, input de tipo file)**

```
<div class="row">  
    
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.users.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
   
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Perfil</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('status_id', 'Estado') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('status_id', $status, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'status_id', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                 
                    <label for="user_photo">Imagen de Perfil</label>
                    <input type="file" id="user_photo" name="user_photo">
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}  
</div>
```

En mi controlador en el **método store trato de almacenar la imagen** con los demás campos del usuario de la siguiente manera:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                 // Validar el formulario
                 $data = $request->validate([
                    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'email'     => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',     
                    'user_photo' => 'required|file',                          
                ]);
                
                // Generar una contraseña
                $data['password'] = str_random(8);
             
                // Creamos el usuario 
                dd($request->all());  
                if (request()->hasFile('user_photo')) {
                    $file = request()->file('user_photo')->store('public');                  
                    $user = new User;   
                    $user->name         = $request->get('name');
                    $user->surname      = $request->get('surname');
                    $user->nickname     = $request->get('nickname');
                    $user->email        = $request->get('email');        
                    $user->password     = $request->get('password');
                    $user->gender       = $request->get('gender');  
                    $user->address      = $request->get('address');
                    $user->postcode     = $request->get('postcode');  
                    $user->city         = $request->get('city');
                    $user->province     = $request->get('province');
                    $user->phone        = $request->get('phone');   
                    $user->user_photo   = $file;
                    $user->save();
                    
                // Enviamos el email
                UserWasCreated::dispatch($user, $data['password']);
              
                }else{
                     return 'no se recibio nada';
                }
    }
```

En mi formulario completo los campos necesarios para completar el perfil del usuario y además selecciono una imagen, **si doy clic al botón crear como pueden observar, lanza un error de validación de campo requerido, cuando yo ya he seleccionado una imagen.**
**Una observacion mas si comento la validación de user:photo como campo requerido, salta el esle del método: no se recibió nada**.

Si se fijan realice una inspeccion con **dd($request->all());**  a mi metodo y este es el resultado.

```
array:15 [
  "_token" => "gRxLpp5fSjPo8aE0XhKCPYJzAlUuqoV6hjhxkvv7"
  "name" => "aa"
  "surname" => null
  "gender" => null
  "email" => "ale@gmail.com"
  "nickname" => null
  "birthdate" => null
  "password" => null
  "password_confirmation" => null
  "status_id" => "1"
  "phone" => null
  "address" => null
  "postcode" => null
  "city" => null
  "province" => null
]
```

El campo user_photo no figura.

**No comprendo que es lo que está sucediendo?**.
Necesito que alguien me de una mano con esto que estoy lidiando hace unos días
**Tiene algo que ver el que allá clonado el proyecto desde mi repositorio?** no se ocurre el porque no esta funcionando mi método store

**ACTUALIZADO 1**

Quisas con esto me puedan orientar, tengo un archivo js para los usuarios.
Con esta acción **($('#modal-btn-save').click(function (event))** básicamente se están validando los campos, si la validación pasa, se crea el usuario, se cierra la modal y se refresca el datatable. Acá en este punto la validación no pasaba porque entendía que no había cargado nada en el **input user_photo**

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href'),
        title = me.attr('title');

    $('#modal-title').text(title);
    $('#modal-btn-save').removeClass('hide')
    .text(me.hasClass('edit') ? 'Actualizar' : 'Crear');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal-body').html(response);
            
            $('#gender').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona un Género',
                tags: true,               
            });

            $('#status_id').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona un Estado',                                    
            });

            $('#province').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona una Provincia',
                tags: true,                            
            });

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,  
                // startDate: date,              
                language: 'es'
            });   
                   
                 
        }
    });

    $('#modal').modal('show');
});

$('#modal-btn-save').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body form'),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    form.find('.help-block').remove();
    form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method: method,
        data : form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            form.trigger('reset');
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();

            swal({
                type : 'success',
                title : '¡Éxito!',
                text : '¡Se han guardado los datos!'
            });
        },
        error : function (xhr) {
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false) {
                $.each(res.errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('#' + key)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .addClass('has-error')
                        .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Prueba con `Form::open(['route' => 'admin.users.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true])`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias por contestar, recien he probado tu sugerencia, y volviendo a probar me lleva al resultado del else (no se recibio nada), es algo muy raro sugiero ir al chat

Comment: ¿Pero pasa la validación? Si es así, usa el reuqest que tienes en la variable, en vez del helper `if ($request->hasFile('user_photo')) { ...`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ recien he cambiado el helper como lo has indicado ```if ($request->hasFile('user_photo')) {$file = $request->file('user_photo')->store('public');```, nuevamente pruebo y me dirige al else, exite otra forma de lograr esto?

Comment: Existe otra manera de inspeccionar o de guardar una imagen es muy raro que no pueda guardar una imagen, existe la posibilidad de que al clonar mi proyecto desde mi respositorio esto interfiera me refiero al archivo .env ya no se que pensar para solucionar.

Comment: no tendrás varios formularios en esa pagina? donde esta el submit??? da la sensación como que no estas mandado el type file

Comment: @pwron  mmmm tengo un archivo js aparte, por ejemplo cuando doy crear en la modal está acción se dirije al .js y ahí se validan los campos si está todo correcto recién ahí guarda voy a subir el archivo js de este formulario podrías revisarlo quisas ahí está mi confusión

Comment: Sugiero ir al chat si es posible.

Comment: verifica que `data : form.serialize(),` contenga la imagen correctamente.

Comment: @Shassain en mi archivo js agregue esto ```$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},});
``` luego  en success trato de hacer un ```console.log(response);```,  pero no logro deserealizar el formulario